# Can I extend my windows 10 partition safely?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I want to take 30 gigs from my ubuntu partition (nvme0n1p5) and give it to my windows partition (nvmeon13p). If I resize from the left, it gives me a warning about it failing to boot potentially. Should I just delete my Ubuntu partition, give it all to Windows, then reinstall Ubuntu with less space? Or is there an easier way that doesn't involve reinstalling everything? 
[Current View From gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwp53.png)

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding what you're saying correctly what you're trying to do will not work because your root partition is currently mounted and active. You must unmount it before you can resize it properly. Unfortunately, you cannot do this while currently using your Linux system, and Windows cannot see ext filesystem partitions. Luckily, you do not have to uninstall Ubuntu to achieve your goal.

I recommend you download the GParted live CD (version 0.30.0-1, or whatever the latest version is) from the developer's [SourceForge page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gparted/files/gparted-live-stable/). You'll want to download the either the i686 (compatible with 32-bit and 64-bit) or amd64 (only 64-bit compatible). Make sure you download the .iso file. Next, you'll have to create a bootable USB or DVD. For KDE, I believe the default disk burner is k3b. If you'll be creating a bootable USB, you can either find a GUI tool or create one yourself using the dd command. The [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media) has a simple guide for using the dd command to create a bootable USB's. There are also numerous forum posts as well.
**Note:** Sometimes dd is successful, but the USB fails to boot. If that happens, you can try another method.

Once inside the GParted live environment, GParted should load automatically and detect your partitions. From here, you can resize your ext4 root partition. Drag from the rightmost side of the partition or right-click on the partition you want to resize and select *resize/move* from the menu that appears. Once your settings are as you want them, apply/save them.

**Do Not** use GParted to resize the Windows partition. This will cause Windows to believe the partition has been damaged and will nag you about running check disk and might even cause damage. Instead, boot into Windows after you've shrunk your Ubuntu partition and use the Disk Management Tool to allocate the free space to your NTFS partitions.

**Warning:** This may be paranoia on my part, but I recommend creating a full backup before doing this just in case something goes wrong.

Comment: +1, don't resize the windows partition with gparted. I learnt this to my cost.

Comment: Would it be easier to boot with the Ubuntu Live USB and run `gparted` from there?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use GParted from inside the Ubuntu live CD just fine. Sorry I didn't realize that earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend to extend a windows/ntfs partition with GParted!

I extended the main partition of my Windows 2012 / Exchange server with GParted. This partition was also the last one on the drive and so the task seemed very simple. I powered it down, extended the disk in ESXi, booted systemrescuecd-6.0.1, and did the extension of the ntfs partition and filesystem with Gparted. Everything seemed to work without error. I could also boot the machine with no problems.
BUT when Veeam wanted to do the daily backup it failed:

```
Event description: Job "nameofjob" finished with error. Processing EXCHANGE Error: VSSControl: -2147467259 Backup job failed. Cannot create a shadow copy of the volumes containing writer's data. VSS asynchronous operation is not completed. Operation: [Shadow copies commit]. Code: [0x8004231f].

EXCHANGE - Failed to prepare guest for hot backup. Error: VSSControl: -2147467259 Backup job failed. Cannot create a shadow copy of the volumes containing writer''s data. VSS asynchronous operation is not completed. Operation: [Shadow copies commit]. Code: [0x8004231f].
```

I've tried tons of things to repair the VSS writer functionality with no success. So I restored the VM for a backup I did before. Did the expansion again with Windows Disk Management. This time everything worked fine.